# Using the button tag, can I customize the button?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to use a custom button image that I drew up for my application, but doing so I need to use different images for the button being focused and another for it being pressed.

I came across the selector tags but for some reason it doesn't like it. Eclipse complains about a 'broken rendering library'. The error I get is this:

```
Broken rendering library; unsupported DPI. Try using the SDK manager to get updated.
```

And I have, I've updated every API past 10. If it matters, my target API is 15 and my compile API is 17.

If I can't get this working, can I simply use the Button tag and maybe change it in the Java src code or something?

Comment: have u tried cleaning the project and restarting eclipse? also, some code would be nice.

Comment: @a_schimpf the code isn't a big deal. It doesn't throw any errors or exceptions. So it does compile, but it crashes. The only error I get is the broken library error.

Comment: are u running the code on the emulator or your phone? does everything run fine without the selector tag code? did you spell this correctly in the xml -- xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"?

Comment: @a_schimpf I run the code on my phone. And it always crashes, and yes it's only with the selector tag. When I use the button tag or ImageButton tag there are no problems, but are not what I need. And everything is written in right, I use Eclipse so a lot of it was templates.

Comment: someone had the same error message here.  it looks like a possible fix. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37472

Answer (score 0):

use a custom layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/pressed"></item>

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focus"></item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal"></item>
</selector>
```

Also note that the the selector should be defined in this particular way else they will give problem .i.e.

```
1)state_pressed
2)state_focused ( work only if you scroll to that button using the hardware key)
3)drawable i.e. normal
```

If you changed the ordering of the selector then it won't work. One easy way to remember it is visualizing a qwerty phone - first i saw the button (`normal`), then moved to that particular button using arrow keys (`state_focused`), then i pressed that button (`state_pressed`). Now write them backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of button,create ImageView and do necessary things on click of the image.

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Method_Name"
        android:src="@drawable/selector" >
    </ImageView>
```

Also inorder to give different images on click and focus,create selector.xml in drawable folder and set background of imageview as selector file.

selector.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

     <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1"  android:state_focussed="true" />
     <!-- Inactive tab -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2"  android:state_pressed="true" />
     <!-- Pressed tab -->


     </selector>
```

Hope this will help you!